# Solve $(1-x^2)dy/dx + 2xy = x(1-x^2)^{1/2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $(1-x^2)dy/dx + 2xy = x(1-x^2)^{1/2}$

I resolved all the terms into exact forms but the coefficients were still non separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Write the equation as
$$d\left(\dfrac{y}{1-x^2}\right)=\dfrac{x}{(1-x^2)^\frac32}dx$$